# How to position background image in the center at the edge of a container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to position two background images (arrows for navigation) either side of a carousel I have setup. Vertical align doesn't seem to be working.

scroll_left & scroll_right are the two divs I want to place either side of the carousel.

```
section.carousel {
    div.container {
        div.row {
            div.carousel_wrapper {
                background-color: #fff;
                width: 100%;
                height: 300px;

                div#scroll_left {
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    background: url( '@{sitePath}/arrow_left.png') center no-repeat;
                    width: 40px;
                    height: 40px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }
                div#scroll_right {
                    float: right;
                    display: block;
                    background: url( '@{sitePath}/arrow_right.png') center no-repeat;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    width: 40px;
                    height: 40px;
                }

                div#carousel_list {
                    div {
                        float: left;
                        img {
                            border-radius: 50%;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: auto;
                            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #333;
                            box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #333;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<div class=\"carousel_wrapper\"><div id=\"scroll_left\"></div>";

echo        "<div id=\"carousel_list\">";

echo            "<div><img src=\"{IMAGE}\"></img></div>";
echo            "<div><img src=\"{IMAGE}\"></img></div>";
echo            "<div><img src=\"{IMAGE}\"></img></div>";

echo        "</div>";

echo "<div id=\"scroll_right\"></div></div>";
```

Comment: Downvoted, for not replying to two substantial answers below. Please at the very least, consider upvoting and/or accepting answers, but a bit of interaction with helpful replies won't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `top:50%` & `translateY(-50%)`

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngjru916/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Simplified code that do the job using `unordered list` tag:

unordered list makes it much easier to design such pages that required elements in different sides of one element.

CSS:

```
<style>    
    #scroll_right {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    #scroll_left {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    #carousel_list {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .carousel_wrapper > li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="carousel_wrapper">
    <li>
        <div id="scroll_left"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul id="carousel_list">
            <li><img src='img/money-tree.jpg'></img></li>
            <li><img src='img/money-tree.jpg'></img></li>
            <li><img src='img/money-tree.jpg'></img></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="scroll_right"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: Just a small comment, but it is `unordered` not `unsigned` list.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this **[pen](http://codepen.io/mofeenster/pen/GvzAF)**

I'd like to point out that it looks like you actually want to vertically align the containing divs that the background images are within, not the background images themselves as they are within small containers.

You can use `vertical-align: middle` with `display: inline-block` on: `div#scroll_left` &  `div#scroll_right`. there isn't much else to say so I'll let the pen do the talking, for reference here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel_wrapper"><div id="scroll_left"></div>
  <div id="carousel_list">
    <div><img src="http://baconmockup.com/300/200"></img></div>
  </div>
<div id="scroll_right"></div>
```

LESS:

```
    div.carousel_wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;

        div#scroll_left {
            display: inline-block;
            background: url( '/arrow_left.png') center no-repeat #000;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        div#scroll_right {
            display: inline-block;
            background: url( '/arrow_right.png') center no-repeat #000;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
        }

        div#carousel_list {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
                img {
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #333;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #333;
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
```